# Checking if a string has no special characters except for ".", "_" and "@"

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently writing a script which checks username & password validity. The username should have between 3 and 20 characters and no special characters, except for ".", "_" and "@".

Currently, this is my function:

```
fun isValidUsername(username: String): Boolean {
    var usrnmlength = true
    var usrnmspecial = true
    
    if ((username.length < 3) or (username.length > 20)) { usrnmlength = false }
    if (username.filter { !it.isLetterOrDigit() }.firstOrNull() != null) {usrnmspecial = false}

    return if ((usrnmlength) and (usrnmspecial)) {
        (true)
    } else {
        (false)
    }

}
```

It checks, if the username has between 3 and 20 characters and if the username has no special characters. But it also says that the username is not valid, if there are the special characters ".", "_" and "@". These should be allowed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the condition for checking special characters to allow ".", "_", and "@" while filtering out other special characters. Here's the updated function:

```
fun isValidUsername(username: String): Boolean {
var usrnmlength = true
var usrnmspecial = true

if ((username.length < 3) or (username.length > 20)) { 
    usrnmlength = false 
}

if (username.filter { !(it.isLetterOrDigit() || it in listOf('.', '_', '@')) }.firstOrNull() != null) {
    usrnmspecial = false
}

return usrnmlength && usrnmspecial
```

}

This modification ensures that the username is considered valid if it has between 3 and 20 characters and contains only letters, digits, ".", "_", or "@".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding a check for the special characters, you can also make some improvements to make your code adhere to [idiomatic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/idioms.html) [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html).

- Prefer immutability. Instead of `var`, use `val` when possible:

  ```
  val usrnmlength = username.length in 3..20
  ```
- Instead of `filter` and checking for `null`, use the existing function `all`:

  ```
  val usrnmspecial = username.all { it.isLetterOrDigit() || it in "._@" }
  ```
- Return a Boolean value directly. It is totally unnecessary to say `if (cond) true else false` when you can just concisely say `cond`:

  ```
  return usrnmlength && usrnmspecial
  ```

Here's the whole function in one go:

```
fun isValidUsername(username: String): Boolean {
    val usrnmlength = username.length in 3..20
    val usrnmspecial = username.all { it.isLetterOrDigit() || it in "._@" }
    return usrnmlength && usrnmspecial
}
```

If you want, you can turn it into an extension function and shorten it even further (smaller code == fewer bugs!)

```
fun String.isValidUsername() =
    length in 3..20 && all { it.isLetterOrDigit() || it in "._@" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in order to check your exact needs.

```
fun String?.isValidUsernameCharacters(): Boolean = this?.matches(Regex("[A-Za-z0-9._@]+")) ?: false
```

Then you can replace your condition and filtering with:

```
usrnmspecial = username.isValidUsernameCharacters()
```